# Random glass block found under snow, what does this mean?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

I found a glass block under some snow, and I was wondering if it meant something. Has anyone else come across this?

Comment: Hi Nina, welcome to the site! is there anything else you can mention about the circumstances of the random glass block? was there a source of lava nearby? what is in the immediate vicinity? what version of minecraft/tekkit are you running?

Comment: And are you playing on a multiplayer server?

Comment: any chance of a screenshot of it?

Comment: It means Winter is Coming.

Comment: @Robotnik The random glass block was just hiding under snow, but also around and under the snow is sand. It is also a block next to a body of water (iced over).
The version im running is the latest.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Yes I am.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe it was sand getting hit by a lightning bolt.

Comment: It was obviosly just a Glitch, Just ignore it. You are just wasting time.

Answer (score 1):

If you dig along those glass towers or blocks you will come to an underground stronghold.

Comment: Any source for this statement?

Answer (score 1):

Just a single block of glass? You're playing on a multiplayer server – some other player placed it there for their own inscrutable reasons.